# Primary G-Suite User Can Send But Not Receive Emails

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator, g-suite-business

The primary user for my G-Suite account can send but no longer receive emails.

I think I may have changed a setting to cause this but I don't know which one.

The primary user email on my G-Suite account has worked for several years in the past with no problems but recently I tried to set up a "catch-all" email rule to have the primary user's email address receive emails that might have been sent to a different email address on my domain by mistake.

Unfortunately, I apparently made a mistake in the process and now my primary user's email can send but won't receive email.

Since I am working with the assumption that my change to the email rules caused the problem, does anyone know a way to reset the email rules back to default?

Because my G-Suite account is a legacy account, I do not have access to any tech support from Google, so without community support I am really stuck.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another user looked at my domain DNS and notified me that [I didn't have any Gsuite mx records](https://intodns.com/geoffstrout.com) on my domain

I checked the MX records and it is as they mentioned; no G-Suite MX records, so I added the recommended G-Suite MX records and it seems to work now.

- Gsuite mx  https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en
- SPF https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en
- DKIM https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en

I don't think those MX records were among the settings I recently changed so I'm still not sure why the email continued working for awhile with those incorrect earlier settings and only recently stopped working.

But it resolved my problem, so I'll post this as an answer to the question, just in case it's helpful to someone else.